# In MVC3, how can I create a route like mydomain.com/chigago and hit that route from a GET form?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an application that shows locations on a map. I have created a route so that I can have nice hackable URLs, like http://www.mydomain.com/paris. This works fine just typing in the URL, but I have a search form on the home page that sends a GET request. When the form is submitted, the URL displayed in the location bar is in the format http://www.mydomain.com/Dashboard?location=paris. Normally this wouldn't matter too much as it's hitting the correct action, but I have a backbone.js application running the show and it's particular about the URL structure.

It may be impossible to do what I need without javascript or a redirect, because the location isn't known when the form ACTION attribute is populated - but can anyone confirm?

Here are my routes.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes( RouteCollection routes )
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute( "{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}" );
    routes.MapRoute(
        String.Empty,
        "{location}",
        new { 
            controller = "Dashboard",
            action = "Index",
            id = ""
        }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new
        {
            controller = "Home",
            action = "Index",
            id = UrlParameter.Optional
        } // Parameter defaults
    );

}
```

Here is the controller.

```
public class DashboardController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ViewResult Index(string location)
    {
        return View(new AccItemSearch { Location = location });
    }
}
```

Here is the form.

```
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Dashboard", FormMethod.Get)) {
                <h2>Where are you going?</h2>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Area, town or postcode" id="location" name="location"/>
                <button>Search!</button>
            </div>
        }
```

**To clarify**: the problem I want help with is how to have the user submit the form then land on a page with the URL: http://www.mydomain.com/searchterm and thus match the route, rather than on a page that with the URL http://www.mydomain.com/Dashboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not be able to change the `action` attribute of the form during HTML generation (i.e. server side) as you simply don't know what it should point to. So if you need the URL to end up being the exact search term the easiest bet is probably to change the `action` attribute to it with JavaScript before the form is submitted, and have a controller that catches all urls that follow the www.domain.com/searchterm pattern.

You can't really redirect to a specific action because then that would become the URL returned to the browser, and I doubt you want one action per search term.

**HTML:**

```
<form method="post" id="myform">
    <input type="text" id="searchterm" />
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(function () {
    $("#myform").submit(function () {
        var searchVal = $("#searchterm").val();
        $(this).attr("action", searchVal);
    });
});
```

**Route:**

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "",
    "{searchterm}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Search" }
);
```

Note that this has to be put *before* the default route(s).

**Action:**

```
public ActionResult Search(string searchterm)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

Now if a visitor enters the term "Alaska" and submits the search form, they will end up on domain.com/Alaska.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to go for this method rather than a redirect as it should overall be quicker (in terms of number of http requests). The voices in my head are always going on about "what about if javascript is disabled" but I'm probably showing my age there. In any case as I'm already using backbone I'm committed!

Comment: I know the feeling regarding the JS thing... but try visiting pages for any major company when you have JS disabled. It usually looks like crap and won't function well at all. Disabling JS and expecting a good browser experience just doesn't float today.

Answer (score 0):

That form should be a POST to submit the form data.

The search should be a submit button

```
 <input type="submit" name="Search" value="Search" />
```

Otherwise it looks good, unless you have a conflicting route.  Tested your route in isolation and it seems fine.  It's just that location is not being sent.

Comment: Hmm, I was using GET deliberately to transmit the data on the querystring. Using POST gets the data into the action, but the URL in the location bar says "http://www.mydomain.com/Dashboard" which isn't what I want.

Comment: to get it to update the url, then Redirect in the post to expected route.  That is have a specific url for the Post, e.g. SearchWith(string location) and within this then RedirectToAction("Index", new {location});  basically the post redirect get pattern.